# How to change the URL a Spring controller is mapped to

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I started learning spring framework, and I can't find alternative method to call controller method, I'm passing querystring varialble in url like - /index.htm?do=login
to call controller method named "login" from my controller

is there any alternative method than this 
which url looks like 
"http://example.com/index.htm" or "http://example.com/index/"

what is @requestMapping and how to use it?

Many thanks!

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
   <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">myController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myController" class="myController">
       <property name="methodNameResolver">
           <ref bean="methodNameResolver"/>
       </property>
   </bean>

      <bean id="methodNameResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.ParameterMethodNameResolver">
       <property name="paramName">
           <value>do</value>
       </property>

    </bean>
```

**myController**

```
public class myController extends MultiActionController {



    public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        return new ModelAndView("login");

    }

}
```

in this code,
I always have to pass query string variable to call matching controller method.
like **"http://example.com/index.htm?do=login"**
this will call login method from controller

but I don't want to use query string variables. how can I do that?
is it possible with **`@RequestMapping`**  to call controller's login method with URL which looks like this : http://example.com/login"

I tried this, but it's not working

```
@RequestMapping("/index.htm")
public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam(value = "do", required = false) String doParam)
{
        return new ModelAndView("login");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is your problem, but for starters:

```
@RequestMapping("/index.htm")
public void index(@RequestParam(value = "do", required = false) String doParam) {
    //...
}
```

The index method will be called for all following URLs:

- `/index.htm` - `doParam` is `null` inside `index()` method
- `/index.htm?do=login` - `doParam` is equal to `login`
- `/index.htm?do=logout` - `doParam` is equal to `logout`

Comment: many many thnx, but i'm still having problem to do what i want to do.. please have a look at my edited question with sample of code.